# how to click on all elements found via xpath by index using selenium,python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, indexing

Am trying to click on all element fetched by x path

```
# Fetching and storing all the matches
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'tg-row')]");
for element in elements:
    # printing the index numbers to confirm it has fetched or not?
    print(element.get_attribute('index'))
```

Am wondering if there is a way to click all the elements found

it tried to initiate `.click()` after the `print(element.ger_attribute...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
for element in elements:
  element.click()
```

Comment: Am getting this error message--->>> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document , what do you think i should do ? @Wasif Hasan